# Zuul Ribbon exception always returns 500 response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am using Zuul with Eureka as a reverse proxy.
When a downstream service returns a 4xx Client Exception, Ribbon will convert the exception into a 500 server error.

An example output on the whitelabel page is:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
403 FORBIDDEN
```

RibbonRoutingFilter appears to always convert any exception to 500.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/route/RibbonRoutingFilter.java#L81

Is there any way to override this behavior and have the original status code sent to the client.

Comment: So I'm trying to reproduce this, and if the client sends back a valid response with a 401, for example, the proper error code is reported back to the client. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/route/RibbonRoutingFilter.java#L76-L77 Do you have a way to reproduce this?

Comment: I was able to reproduce using a 503 which is a special case in ribbon. If you have a project that can reproduce this, create an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [known issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/406) that we plan on fixing.